# How to configure the Auth0 login page authorize URL as default login page in angular application?

Tags: authentication, uri, auth0, openid-connect

To configure the application login URI in Auth0 for Single Page Application. 
To redirect to the Auth0 login page automatically, when the application URL is typed in the browser. Instead of triggering the Login page from browser via button or some other action.